# Change of variables for $k$-forms

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

For $T(u,v) = (2u+3v, 5u-2v)$, find the following:
1) $(\omega_0)_T$ of $\omega_0 = f(x,y) = x^2-y$
2) $(\omega_1)_T$ of $\omega_1 = -y~dx+x~dy$
3) $(\omega_1)_T$ of $\omega_2 = \sin (x+y) ~dx~dy$

I'm having trouble trying to apply the change of variables theorem directly, so I've instead been trying to find similar problems or examples that could help me tackle the above questions, but to no avail.

EDIT: Would this method work?: [Coordinate change in a differential form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166663/coordinate-change-in-a-differential-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically substituting 
$$x = 2u + 3v,\ \ \ y = 5u-2v$$
in the expression and apply the usual rule. 
$$ d f(u, v) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (u, v) du + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (u, v) dv.$$
For example for $\omega_1$,

$$\begin{split}
(\omega_1)_T &= -(5u-2v) d(2u+ 3v) + (2u+3v) d(5u-2v) \\
&= -(5u-2v) (2du + 3dv) + (2u+3v)(5du-2dv) \\
&= (-2(5u-2v) + 5(2u+3v)) du + (-3(5u-2v) -2 (2u+3v))dv \\
&= 19v du -19u dv 
\end{split}
$$

Comment: This confirmed what I was thinking, I just wanted to make sure. Thank you very much!